# I'm not clear why the reasoning that M. Nair used is valid in one of his classic proofs.

Tags: integration, inequality, proof-explanation, least-common-multiple

I am reading through M. Nair's [On Chebyshev-Type Inequalities for Primes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320934) and I am unclear on why one of his key steps is valid.

Let $d_n$ be the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $1,2,\dots,n$ such that:

> $$d_n = \text{lcm}_{1\le m \le n}\{ m \}$$

Here is the reasoning that seems suspect to me for $n \ge 1$.

> $$I = \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r{n\choose r}x^{n+r} dx = \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r}\frac{1}{n+r+1} $$

Since $n+r+1 \le 2n+1$, it follows that:

> $$Id_{2n+1} \in \mathbb{N}$$

Since $x(1-x) \le \frac{1}{4}$, it follows that:

> $$I \le \frac{1}{4^n}$$

And from this that:

> $$d_{2n+1} > 4^n$$

But if this is valid reasoning.

What's wrong with using the same logic to observe that:

> $$I = \int_0^1 x^n(1-2x)^n dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{r=0}^n (-2)^r{n\choose r}x^{n+r} dx = \sum_{r=0}^n (-2)^r {n\choose r}\frac{1}{n+r+1} $$

And then, since $x(1-2x) \le \frac{1}{8}$ that:

> $$I \le \frac{1}{8^n}$$

And further that:

> $$d_{2n+1} > 8^n$$

Could someone help me to understand why the first set of steps is valid and why my counter example is not valid?

Comment: You are assuming that $|x(1-2x)|\le\frac18$, not using $x(1-2x)\le\frac18$.

Comment: If $|x(1-2x)| \le \frac{1}{8}$, isn't $x(1-2x) \le \frac{1}{8}$?

Comment: The trouble is, that $|x(1-2x)|\not\le\frac18$ in general.

Comment: You said it! You had a proof that $x(1-2x)\le1/8$ given to you just today. why are you suddenly assuming that's false?

Comment: Sorry.  Let me ask it another way.  Are you saying that my reasoning incorrectly assumes that $|x(1-2x)| \le \frac{1}{8}$  Could you help me to understand why this assumption is necessary and why it doesn't apply to $x(1-x) \le \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: $y\le\frac18$ does not imply $y^n\le1/8^n$.

Comment: Got it!  Now I am clear on your point.  It is only true if $n$ is odd.  Shouldn't this then also be an objection to Nair's reasoning?

Comment: $0\le y\le\frac18$ does imply $y^n\le(\frac18)^n$.

Comment: $0\le x(1-x)\le\frac14$ when $0\le x\le1$.

Comment: Thanks @bof.  Now, I am clear.  If you post that as the answer, I will be glad to accept it.  Cheers.